# Why doesn't (the standard way of) making an element 100% the height of its parent work in Safari when the parent's a flex item?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I'm using the method of making a child element 100% the height of its parent that's most commonly given in StackOverflow answers, namely relative-positioning the parent, and then giving the child these styles:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

But, please take a look at [this Codepen implementation of the above](https://codepen.io/taurog/pen/vYKaXLd). In it, I make the parent element a flex item and the child element a table (or a `<div>` with `display: table`). I need to do this for my client's real world design case, partly to vertically align the text in the middle, which I believe only tables can do.

As you can see, it breaks in Safari. But It looks like the CSS should work, and it does in Chrome. Why's it breaking in Safari? How can I fix this?

PS: I'm open to alternative approaches to making the child 100% the height of its flex item parent, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the parent display: flex; flex-direction: column; and the child flex-grow:1; it should work.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
      Content
  </div>
</div>
```

- 

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.child{
  flex-grow:1;
  background:red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Check this [code pen](https://codepen.io/gabdsg/pen/wvWxYxz)

Comment: That's what I already have in [the Codepen](https://codepen.io/taurog/pen/vYKaXLd): `#flex_outer_container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;} .flex_item {
 flex-grow: 1;}`. Have you tried editing the Codepen, and what edits work if so?

Comment: @tog22 you should remove the tables, check the code pen in my answer

Comment: Ah thanks, but the point of my question was that I *need* to have a table (or `display: table` element) there to vertically align the text in the middle. Sorry my question wasn't clear enough, have edited. Can you see what's going wrong in my specific Codepen?

Comment: You don't need a table to vertically align the text. Just use a flex container.
I updated my code pen.

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know about the `align-items` features of flexbox! I appreciate your help greatly, sincere thanks Gabriel  I'd accept your answer, but I'll leave my question open in case anyone can explain whether there was something wrong with my original CSS or it was just a Safari bug, as that'll help further my understanding of CSS.